# Office365: 411 content-length required

Tags: java, office365-restapi

Here i am trying to update the user in office 365 through rest api. while trying the below code

```
String data = {"displayName": "kannan",
  "userPrincipalName": "kannan@sennovate.onmicrosoft.com",
  "manager": "0d891c03-b125-4126-b10f-c64c74c3aaac",
  "accountEnabled": "true",
  "mailNickname": "kannan",
  "usageLocation": "IN"}

conn.setRequestMethod("PATCH");             
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length()));
```

It's returning response code as `411`, content length required. But I already set the value. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (your array instantiation is invalid and an array doesn't have a length method). Also the content length is the length of the content, not the number of strings in the array. Finally your rest client may automatically insert a content length - which client are you using?

Comment: You should post all relevant code.

Comment: 1) `data` is not a `String`, it is not even valid Java syntax. 2) What class is `conn` an instance of?